# How should I fix an odd action URL?

Tags: plugin-development, request, elementaction

I have a controller which is eventually going to be set up for POSTs and GETs, but the weird thing is I can only access it through `localhost/index.php?p=actions/twoFA/get` where twoFA is my plugin handle and get is an action method in my controller. How can I make it so that it behaves like all the examples online where I could go to `localhost/actions/twoFA/get`? What's happening? Also, my `actionTrigger` is set to `actions` and I have not set up any site routes in my plugin.

UPDATE: I have decided to make this work a little differently, and I therefore do not need any help.

Comment: Went ahead and voted to close as OP stated it's no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

In Craft 3 the csrf token validation in the `general.php` config is set to true by default. In order to request your controller with post requests you have to turn it off or include the token

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#csrf-token-params

```
{% set csrfTokenName = craft.app.config.general.csrfTokenName %}         
{% set csrfToken = craft.app.request.csrfToken %}     
<input type="hidden" name="{{ csrfTokenName }}" value="{{ csrfToken }}">
```

Comment: this doesn't really answer my question

Comment: Seems like I missunderstood it. I thought it was about not being able to access it via POST request